# Putting greek letters in column names

Tags: r, symbols, r-colnames

Is there any way to include Greek letters (α,β,γ) into column names of a matrix? I know you use:

```
colnames()<-c("column 1","column 2","column 3".....)
```

to add column names but when i tried to paste in the letters...

```
colnames(mymatrix)<-c("random name","parameters(α,β,γ)","parameters2(α,β,γ)")
```

it shows the "(α,β,γ)" as "(??,??,??)"

How can this be done?

Comment: It works fine for me on a Mac, but I would avoid using anything other than plain text for names.

Comment: Yeah i just found that it actually works on r, it saves fine as a picture too but pasting that picture into word is when the symbols disappear and are replaced by the question marks....which is kinda strange :/

Comment: What do you mean by "as a picture"? If you plot the matrix you should probably use expression(alpha) instead of "α".

Comment: I saved the matrix as a table and then used `png()` to save it as a picture to put it into a document easily. does `expression(alpha) work if it is within "" because i need it to be combined with "Parameters of in-sample(alpha,beta,gamma)"

Comment: In that case you should use something like `expression(paste("Parameters of in-sample(", alpha, ",", beta, 
+     ",", gamma, ")", sep = ""))`

Comment: @SummerGleek You will not be able to use expressions as column names of matrices. Colnames need to be character vectors. I'm realizing that you now you really need to edit this question to add all the missing code example and workflow if you want a stable answer.