# Barplot: Greek letters on y axis in R

Tags: r, unicode, bar-chart

This is a follow-up question to my other question on barplots:
[Tornado plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059281/tornado-plot-in-r)

I realized the question about getting greek letters on the y-axis needed to be asked as an own question.

The question is:
I have the following barplot and need to change the y-axis to respective greek letters (and a V with a bar over).

[image]

I use the following code:

```
# Tornado plot

data <- matrix(c(-0.02,0.02,-0.01,0.01,-0.03,0.02,-0.01,0.04), ncol = 4)
rownames(data) <- c('+10%','-10%')
colnames(data) <- c('V_bar', 'alpha', 'rho','xi')
x <- seq(-0.04,0.04, length=10)

barplot(data[1,], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.04,0.04), xaxt='n', ylab='',
        beside=T, col=c('springgreen'))
barplot(data[2,], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.04,0.04), xaxt='n',
        yaxt='n',                 #To prevent double printing of y-labels.
        beside=T, col=c('indianred2'), add = TRUE)
axis(1, at=pretty(x),  lab=paste0(pretty(x) * 100," %"), las=TRUE)
```

To get the greek letters I have tried the following:

```
 barplot(data[2,], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.04,0.04), xaxt='n', 
         yaxt= c(expression(bar(V)), expression(alpha),expression(rho), expression(xi)),
         beside=T, col=c('indianred2'), add = TRUE))
```

and

```
axis(2, at=c(1:4), lab = expression(xi ~ rho ~ alpha ~ bar(V)), las=T)
```

or

```
axis(2, at=pretty(x), lab = paste0(expression(xi ~ rho ~ alpha ~ bar(V)), las=T))
```

But no success. Anyone now the trick?

Note. I have seen this question: [Adding greek character to axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044800/adding-greek-character-to-axis-title)
But it focuses on the labels, not the y-axis "values".
Also, I have tried something like [Putting greek letters in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179741/putting-greek-letters-in-column-names)
with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call `axis` for labeling of the bars if you provide the argument `names.arg` to `barplot`:

```
barplot(data[1,], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.04,0.04), xaxt='n', ylab='',
    beside=T, col=c('springgreen'),
    names.arg=c(expression(xi),expression(rho), expression(alpha), expression(bar(V))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass `lab` in `axis` as a vector of `expression`s.

```
axis(2, at=c(1:4), lab = c(expression(xi),
 expression(rho), expression(alpha), expression(bar(V))), las=T)
```

Then you can play with the settings of the axis as needed.